# Kubernetes deploy multiple instances of same app on dedicated URLs

Tags: kubernetes, containers, azure-aks

I have a simple containerised web app deployed to AKS, all works fine. Next step I'd like to take is to deploy X-instances same web app, each on dedicated URLs, differentiated by path or ports. This is so I can run automated tests against this web app, each test on a dedicated URL (relying on sticky sessions won't work)

It does not seem like replicas can do it, as they are not addressable with a dedicated URL/port. And following many tutorials on web, I'm struggling to come up with a yaml definition that would achieve this "elegantly" (i.e. in one Deployment)

Any ideas?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app-name
  namespace: namespace-name
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app-name
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app-name
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app-name
        image: image_xyz
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app-name-service
  namespace: namespace-name
  labels:
    app: app-name
    tier: frontend
spec:
  type: ClusterIP 
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: app-name
    tier: frontend
    
---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-name-ingress
  namespace: namespace-name
spec:
  rules:
  - host: app.host.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: app-name-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

Comment: It sounds like you've laid out the steps you need to take in the question already: you need _n_ copies of the Deployment, Service, and Ingress objects, somehow differentiated from each other (different namespaces would be an easy way), with different paths in the Ingress.  You might look at tools like [Helm](https://helm.sh) that can apply a templating engine to customize parts of the YAML at deployment time.

Comment: Thanks for the comment David. I'm not using Helm (yet). Isn't there a "simpler" implementation with one Deployment?

Comment: Unless you can implement the URL routing in your application itself, not really.  Otherwise each URL path needs its own Ingress (or its own rule), targeting a distinct Service, which would need to target a separate Deployment (set of Pod labels).  A Deployment's replicas are identical and so you can't set up separate Services to target the individual Pods.

Comment: You could use istio to do most of that without multiple services etc, if you're willing to set it up.

Comment: Thank you Chris for bringing istio to my attention. That would be in my situation a lot more effort then Helm. But it's good to be aware of it

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor nothing dynamic for now, I could not find a way (without installing the other tools on AKS). I've just manually replicated the 1 deployment a few times

Comment: @user1275154, have you found any solution for this?